# Replace zero length mail merge field with user input

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a MS Word template where I have certain mail-merge fields and one of those fields in the source doucment is sometimes empty. I am using below IF condition and taking user's input for the date field but I cannot update the source mail merge document with this information.

```
If Len(ActiveDocument.MailMerge.DataSource.DataFields("startDate").Value) < 1 Then
    InputStartDate = Format(InputBox("Enter Commenced date ..."), "mm/dd/yyyy")
    ActiveDocument.MailMerge.DataSource.DataFields("startDate").Value = InputStartDate
End If
```

I get an error here that says mail merge source doucment field connot be edited or is locked, something like this.

Is there any way through which I could either update the source field and through application refresh method, I populate that mail merge field with this user input date?

Alternatively I could otherwise add a few lines of code to perform following steps:
1- Save this document (using Saveas2 method) as ".docx" by converting it from ".docm" 
2- Break the mail merge connection through VBA code
3- Select all mail merge fields and using Sendkeys "CTRL+SHIFT+F9" covert all of them to normal strings.
4- Make that particular mail-merge field a Bookmark field and then finally update that bookmark field with the user input.

This sounds like a longer route of getting a simple **empty mail merge field issue** fixed but this is so far all that I could think of. If you have any better suggestion, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

### Instead of vba, do this with fields. Then it becomes part of the Mail Merge.

```
{ IF { MergeField startDate } > 0 "{MergeField starttDate }" "{ FillIn "What is the Start Date?" }" }
```

This will trigger the Fill-In field unless there is content in the startDate field for the record.

- Here is [documentation on the Fill-In Field](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/field-codes-fill-in-field-aa773538-91ee-446a-9a58-1cff8db21d59).
- Here is [documentation on the IF Field](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/field-codes-if-field-9f79e82f-e53b-4ff5-9d2c-ae3b22b7eb5e).
- Here is [my tutorial on the Ask and Fill-In Fields](http://addbalance.com/word/download.htm#AskField).
- Here is my article on [Dealing With Fields in Microsoft Word](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/dealing-with-fields-in-microsoft-word/e1bdddad-5a51-4327-837c-c3786c16a501).
- Here is Word MVP Paul Edstein's Tutorial on [Mailmerge Tips and Tricks](http://www.msofficeforums.com/mail-merge/21803-mailmerge-tips-tricks.html).

Comment: Hi Charles, Thanks for your response. I used your code as a field instead of editing my macro because I believe it is meant to be used as a document field. And since doucment  already has a mailmerge connection, the MergeField used in this field formula will correspond to the retrieved value from the actual mailmerge source field to check the length of StartDate field (correct me if I am wrong). Due to some odd reason I get a syntax error.   Also advise if we have to insert "=" sign at the begining of field formula?

Comment: Sorry, I corrected it above. No, no = sign is needed.